# app crashes while fetching images from server on some devices

Tags: android

I am fetching images from a server and setting it in a list view. The problem is that it is working properly in many devices but in some devices it crashes while downloading for first the time.

But when I try to do it again it opens without any problem. For the first time it says out of memory error. is this problem related to coding or its just related to heap memory of devices?
here's the log-

```
07-19 16:22:04.050: E/image_url(14776): http://siliconsoftwares.in/real_json/uploads/property/agent/three hindustani/DSC_0145.jpg
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:599)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at com.example.realstate.FeaturedPropertiesActivity$ImageLoader.doInBackground(FeaturedPropertiesActivity.java:235)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at com.example.realstate.FeaturedPropertiesActivity$ImageLoader.doInBackground(FeaturedPropertiesActivity.java:1)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-19 16:22:04.060: E/AndroidRuntime(14776):    ... 5 more
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776): Activity com.example.realstate.FeaturedPropertiesActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4442ee10 that was originally added here
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.realstate.FeaturedPropertiesActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4442ee10 that was originally added here
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at com.example.realstate.FeaturedPropertiesActivity$DownloadPropertiesList.onPreExecute(FeaturedPropertiesActivity.java:174)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at com.example.realstate.FeaturedPropertiesActivity.downloadPropertiesList(FeaturedPropertiesActivity.java:98)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at com.example.realstate.FeaturedPropertiesActivity.onCreate(FeaturedPropertiesActivity.java:62)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-19 16:22:04.630: E/WindowManager(14776):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 16:22:05.490: D/dalvikvm(14776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 121K, 8% free 43275K/46919K, paused 41ms, total 42ms
07-19 16:22:05.540: D/dalvikvm(14776): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 17K, 8% free 43257K/46919K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
07-19 16:22:05.540: E/dalvikvm-heap(14776): Out of memory on a 21233680-byte allocation.
```

Comment: Can't say anything without looking into what you are trying!

Comment: can you post your log here.

Comment: Look into ? Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: yes that's what i'm saying that it only crashes on some devices such as karbonn or micromax but doesnt crashes on sony or samsung.What's the reason for that?